# PHP - running function returns empty page

Tags: php, mysql

When I run the following PHP code in my browser, I get an empty page in return. Why is this so?

```
<?php 

require_once "conf.php";

function nuser()
{
    $fname = $_POST['name'];
    $uname = $_POST['user'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO websign(name,uname,email,pass)VALUES('$fname','$user','$email','$pass')";
    $data = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
    if ($data)
    {
        echo "your registration is completed";
    }
}
function signup()
{
   .......
   .......
}
?>
```

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL-injection. Never ever trust and use user-submitted data in your queries. Also, please extend your question with error messages (maybe you can found them in logs).

Comment: A php function will run when you call it, where do you call `nuser()`? Where the `$_POST` came from? And you shouldn't use mysql_query, it's deprecated : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: In your given sample code you are using 2 functions. But, from nowhere you are calling those functions. So, nothing is executing & due to nothing is there to show up.

Comment: You don't _actually_ have raw passwords saved in your database do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't *do* anything.

You have defined two functions, but you never call either of them.

You need to add `nuser()` to the end of the script.

---

This assumes that the script executes at all. You said "when i run it on browser", but PHP doesn't run in browsers, it runs on servers. See [this question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page).

---

Your program might also fail because you are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) that has been [removed](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php) from PHP. You should select a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.